# If image not found, increment instead of displaying new every time

Tags: php, html, json, function, logging

**I am using this function to get the two-letter country code:**

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
function ip_details($ip) {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}");
    $details = json_decode($json);
    return $details;
}
```

**Output:**

```
US // Two-letter Country Code
```

**To make a log in a file, I used this:**

```
$pathVisitorsFile = 'visitors.txt'; // file path
$details = ip_details($ipaddress);
file_put_contents($pathVisitorsFile, $details->country . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

**For reading the entries:**

```
$visitorsCountry = file($pathVisitorsFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// Count entries
$foundCountries = array();
foreach($visitorsCountry as $visitorCountry) {
    if(!isset($foundCountries[$visitorCountry])) {
        $foundCountries[$visitorCountry] = 1;
    } else {
        $foundCountries[$visitorCountry]++;
    }
}
```

**To display the flags, I have this:**

```
foreach($foundCountries as $countryCode => $visitors) {
$file_to_check="img/$countryCode.png"; // image path
    if (file_exists($file_to_check)){
        echo('<li><img src="' . $file_to_check . '" />' . $visitors . '</li>');
    } else {
        echo('<li><img src="images/unknown.png" />' . $visitors . '</li>');
    }                   
}
```

**Situation:** I am using a `forloop` for displaying country flags which creates a new `<li>` only if the two letter country code is different and doesn't exist already. Otherwise, it increments it.

**Problem:** I don't have images for a lot of country codes so I used the `file_exists($file_to_check)` function to display a `unknown.png` flag if the image for the country code doesn't exist. Now, if the country code is different and the image doesn't exist, it displays the same unknown flag for each of them. **I would like it to display only 1 `unknown.png` flag and increment it every time.**

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you just want to count the country of the visitors? either add google analytics to your site , on process the exiting access log with AWstats et al

Comment: Just wanted to keep it simple for now and go with a flat file and using an api to get the country of the visitor. It is for a personal site so I don't think it will be going too crazy.

Comment: i find both the above options far simpler - may be that's just me :-)

Comment: Not sure why this was -1. +1'd for you

Comment: @BradlySpicer thank you! I was wondering the same... I have made the question as clear as possible! any idea on it?

Comment: @imbondbaby The only suggestion I could make, that i'm not 100% on is nesting an if statement which would increment it. What is the thing you're incrementing?

Comment: Well here's an example: If it shows 1 visitor for US and another one goes on the page or refreshes it... it increments it by 1 so now it will show 2. Hope that answers your question!

Comment: Do you want an increment for EACH flag visitor? so a counter for the UK, One for the US etc? if so. I know the theory behind it

Comment: So initially it should start with no flag being displayed until a user from that country goes on the page... then it should start incrementing from there... But like I said in the question... If there are multiple unkown flags intead of incrementing, it displays the unknown flag that many times because of different country codes

Comment: @imbondbaby have a look at the code below. It might work?

Comment: @BradlySpicer I was hoping to use a flat file but will try the MySQL way later today when I have time... Thanks for posting the answer!

Comment: @imbondbaby keep me updated, eager to know how it goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the country code for countries without a flag to "unknown", and continually increment the counter.  Once you're done checking all of the country codes, you can output the generated HTML, like so:

*save to demo.php, chmod +x demo.php && ./demo.php*

---

```
    #!/usr/bin/php
    <?php

    $foundCountries = array(
      'US' => 10,
      'UK' => 5,
      'RU' => 12,
      'CA' => 21,
    );

    $unknownVisitors = 0;  //separate counter for "unknown" visitors
    $html = array();      //array to store generated html

    //loop through and generate the html, putting all countries that don't have a flag image/
    //into the "unknown" country code.
    //this could be optimized further, having only one line that generates all of the html by
    //setting the value of $file_to_check to whatever image you want to use. 
    foreach($foundCountries as $countryCode => $visitors) {
        $file_to_check="img/$countryCode.png"; // image path
        if (file_exists($file_to_check)){
          $html[$countryCode] = '<li><img src="' . $file_to_check . '" />' . $visitors . '</li>'; //fixed a slight bug(?) in the original code that generated "img/$countryCode.png$countryCode"
        } else {
          $unknownVisitors += $visitors;
          $html['unknown'] = '<li><img src="images/unknown.png" />' . $unknownVisitors . '</li>';
        }                   
    }

    //output the html
    foreach($html as $cc => $code)
      echo "$code" . PHP_EOL;
```

---

Sample Output:

```
<li><img src="img/US.png" />10</li>
<li><img src="img/UK.png" />5</li>
<li><img src="images/unknown.png" />33</li>
```

Comment: I can not set a country code for all the unknown countries... I don't have the complete list for all the country codes supported and also I will be putting in 40+ lines for this.... Is there any other way?

Comment: It's sample code -- you should use your code to load the data into `$foundCountries`, and it will work.  The $foundCountries declaration I have was just so the sample code would run successfully.

Comment: Sorry, took long to get back... you code is closer to what I want but now the problem is `$unknownVisitors += $visitors;` is incrementing the number of unknown flags but also displaying that many unknown flags as well. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: In your sample code isn't it showing the total number of visitors with unknown flags (33)?

Comment: http://oi59.tinypic.com/23mwnkn.jpg this is how its looking... it is incrementing the number of times but also showing that many flags

Comment: Can you post the code that generates that image?  When I tested my sample code it only generated one < img > tag.

Comment: Take a look here... like you said yours was a sample code so I had to implement int into my code http://www.privatepaste.com/download/d2717e943a and I started a new counter for the unknown visitors in the `else` statement in `file_exists`

Comment: You didn't actually implement the code I provided.  Your problem is mainly in the follwing statement: `    if(!isset($foundCountries[$visitorCountry])) {
        $foundCountries[$visitorCountry] = 1;
    } else {
        $foundCountries[$visitorCountry]++;
    }`
See the code I provided above.

Comment: I don't want to have an array with values like you have it for $foundCountries... I am getting data from the text file like in my code.. Can you edit the code to make the changes

Comment: The array was **just for the demo code**.  Use your own code to populate `$foundCountries`.

Comment: @imbondbaby - Just wondering how your conversion to using a database went.  Also please note -- that website has a hard 1,000 request-per-day limit.  I can implement that as well if you'd like. LMK. trick.developer@gmail.com-Trick

Answer (score 0):

Create a column in the database called Visitor_Counter or something along those lines.
Now, each time you call this php function you will be running an auto increment, so we need to `SELECT` the Database first *(MYSQLI)*.

```
if ($query= $mysqli->query("SELECT Visitor_Counter FROM DATABASE ")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $query->num_rows);
```

Once we've selected these, we need to make an increment code in PHP.

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Visitor_Counter"], $row["Country"]);
}

$next_auto_inc = $row['Visitor_Counter'] + 1;
```

I'm not sure if this is 100% correct, but this is in my head, correct :)

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple add a
 break;
Statement after echoing the unkown flag so you can exit the loop.

Comment: break only displays one unknown flag but doesn't increment the counter